# Changing Hyperlink Column based on InfoPath forms

Tags: infopath, column, hyperlink

I have a requirement from my client that's unlike anything I've done in SP.  So, I'm re-designing their Change Request system.  I've build a form with multiple views in InfoPath that serve different purposes and will kick off notification email workflows as the Change Request moves along.  So I have a column on my SP 2013 list entitled "Actions".  This column serves as a status update display for those who look at the list.  Currently when a user clicks on a New Item, they're prompted to fill out the initial Change Request form, then submit it.  It populates on the List just fine.  However, the Actions column now indicates the next step to be taken, "Initial Triage".  This is a view in my InfoPath form.  I'd like to make the content in the Actions column "clickable" and redirect the user to the appropriate new form to fill out.  Upon filling it out and submitting that form, the Actions column changes yet again and allows the user to move to the next form to fill out.

I know that's a mouthful, but is there any way I can accomplish this?  Any help would be amazing.

Thank you,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infopath lets you add a query string to the end of your form link that specifies the view to open. For instance, adding `&DefaultView=View3` to the end of the URL will open the specified view.

If this is SharePoint Online or SharePoint 2019 you can use column formatting to specify the link.

Here's a sample format for your Actions column:

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "='https://domain/locationofinfopathform.aspx?ID=' + [$ID] + '&DefaultView=' + @currentField"
  }
}
```

If this is SharePoint 2019, you'll need to rewrite it like this:

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "href": {
      "operator": "+",
      "operands": [
        "https://domain/locationofinfopathform.aspx?ID=",
        "[$ID]",
        "&DefaultView=",
        "@currentField"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can apply formats directly in the modern list view. Detailed instructions can be found here (along with lots of samples): https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-list-formatting/gettingstarted/columnformats/

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response.  Would the above code be placed in a Script Editor snippet, or a Content Editor?

Comment: Can you confirm what version of SharePoint you are using?